# Percorrer uma lista com each em Jquery

Tags: jquery

Estou com dificuldades em abrir individualmente cada opção dessa lista para mostrar a informação correspondente de cada item

**HTML**

```
<ul class="lista">
      <li class="item">
           <strong>Item 1</strong>
           <div class="texto">
              <p>Descrição do item 1...</p>
           </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
           <strong>Item 2</strong>
           <div class="texto">
              <p>Descrição do item 2...</p>
           </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
           <strong>Item 3</strong>
           <div class="texto">
              <p>Descrição do item 3...</p>
           </div>
      </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('div.texto').hide() // ocultando a descrição dos itens
      $('li.item').each(function(){ // percorrendo cada elemento da lista
             this.click(function(){ // cada vez que clico em um elemento da lista é lançado uma função
             $('div.texto').toggle() // o texto é mostrado ou ocultado novamente
    })
  })
})
```

Estou utilizando a versão do [Jquery 3.2.1](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js%22%20integrity=%22sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN%22%20crossorigin=%22anonymous%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

**PS:** Até onde eu entendi pelos comentários, meu código está fazendo isso, qual informação está faltando para que a função realmente seja executada de forma correta.

Comment: Ao tratar o evento `click` do elemento `li.item` você faz `$('div.texto').toggle()`. Como o jQuery saberia sobre qual elemento `div.texto` ele deveria atuar? Como é um elemento filho do `<li>`, então pode reduzir a sua busca dos elementos para apenas elementos filhos. Pode pesquisar pela função `children` do jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Não há necessidade da chamada à função `each()`.

O mais simples seria chamar a função `$('.lista .item').click()` que monitora por cliques em todos os `<li class="item">`.

Veja no código abaixo:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div.texto').hide() // ocultando a descrição dos itens

        $('.lista .item').click(function(){
            //Ocultar se houver alguma descrição anterior sendo exibida:
            $('div.texto').hide();

            //Buscar a tag com class="texto" filha do item clicado e exibi-la:
            $(this).find('.texto').show();
        });
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="lista">
      <li class="item">
           <strong>Item 1</strong>
           <div class="texto">
              <p>Descrição do item 1...</p>
           </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
           <strong>Item 2</strong>
           <div class="texto">
              <p>Descrição do item 2...</p>
           </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
           <strong>Item 3</strong>
           <div class="texto">
              <p>Descrição do item 3...</p>
           </div>
      </li>
</ul>
```